# Youtube Video doesn't stop playing when Bootstrap Modal closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, video

I have a Bootstrap Modal on my site that automatically plays a youtube video when it pops up. The modal closes when I click on the top right corner X button and the video stops playing. However, when I close the modal by clicking outside the video pop up window, the video keeps playing in the background. Also, when I click on the launch button, the video plays automatically.

**How can I make it so that the video stops playing when I click outside the video pop up window?**

The following is my HTML code for the modal with the youtube video:

```
<button id="launch-button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-theVideo="http://www.youtube.com/embed/loFtozxZG0s"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></button>
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                </div>
                <!-- BODY -->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <iframe width="100%" height="350" src="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The following is my JavaScript code:

```
function autoPlayYouTubeModal(){
    var trigger = $("body").find('[data-toggle="modal"]');
    trigger.click(function() {
        var theModal = $(this).data( "target"),
            videoSRC = $(this).attr( "data-theVideo"),
            videoSRCauto = videoSRC+"?autoplay=1" ;
        $(theModal+' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
        $(theModal+' button.close').click(function () {
            $(theModal+' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
        })
    })
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    autoPlayYouTubeModal();
})
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I believe you want .blur

Comment: .blur? Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: .blur is an event handler that fires when an element loses focus.  In your case, you can use the blur event to stop your video from playing. https://api.jquery.com/blur/

Comment: Like this?` function autoPlayYouTubeModal(){
    var trigger = $("body").find('[data-toggle="modal"]');
    trigger.click(function() {
        var theModal = $(this).data( "target"),
            videoSRC = $(this).attr( "data-theVideo"),
            videoSRCauto = videoSRC+"?autoplay=1" ;
        $(theModal+' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
        $(theModal+' button.close').click(function () {
            $(theModal+' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
        })
        $(theModal+' iframe').blur(function(){
            $(theModal+' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
        })
    })
}`

Comment: You should probably use [YouTube's JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) which will allow you to more finely control the playback of the video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure it out just in case anyone is having the same issue.

I added:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
    // do something...
})
```

to my javascript code. The end result looks like this:

```
function autoPlayYouTubeModal(){
    var trigger = $("body").find('[data-toggle="modal"]');
    trigger.click(function() {
        var theModal = $(this).data( "target"),
            videoSRC = $(this).attr( "data-theVideo"),
            videoSRCauto = videoSRC+"?autoplay=1" ;
        $(theModal+' iframe').attr('src', videoSRCauto);
        $(theModal+' button.close').click(function () {
            $(theModal+' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
        })
        $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { // new code
            $(theModal+' iframe').attr('src', videoSRC);
        })
    })
}
```

Hope this helps!